# Problem pushing MSI via SMS to hosts that have Windows XP SP3 installed

Tags: installation, windows-installer, sms, windows-xp-sp3

I've created an MSI that installs our application. It installs fine if you run it locally on a machine with Windows XP SP2 or SP3. If you run it through SMS to a machine that has Windows XP SP2 it installs fine. But, if you try to run it through SMS to a machine that has Windows XP SP3 it seems to stall and take hours. (It only takes a couple of minutes when run via the other methods.)

Does anyone have any insight as to why it is behaving this way with SMS and XP SP3?

**Update**

Our SMS guys think they found the problem. We had asked them to do a reboot before the install. They said that on SP3, some services weren't being started before the installer was running. They think this was causing the problem. They're going to try adding a delay after the reboot before the install starts.

Comment: Does it get held up when deploying via SMS only, i.e. a regular command line silent install with `MSIEXEC` is fine?

Comment: Yes, running via msiexec worked fine. I asked for logs from our SMS group, but haven't received them.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the system's Event Log, as you will likely see any remote errors there.  If nothing shows that seems pertinent, then check any logs that SMS generates to see if you can determine what the hold-up is.

Answer (score 0):

Might you be able to turn on [windows installer logging](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1127) and see where things are getting held up? I'm not sure where the `%TEMP%` folder would be for the SMS/SYSTEM account tho...